# EC2: multiple subdomains with one public IPv4 address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i have many EC2 instances, each of which currently has a public IPv4 address associated with it:

| Instance | Public IP | DNS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `juno` | `7.8.9.10` | `ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com` |
| `ceres` | `7.8.9.11` | `ec2-1-2-3-5.compute-1.amazonaws.com` |
| `venus` | `7.8.9.12` | `ec2-1-2-3-6.compute-1.amazonaws.com` |

i currently have my DNS configured to point subdomains to each instance like this:

| Subdomain | CNAME |
| --- | --- |
| `juno` | `ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com` |
| `ceres` | `ec2-1-2-3-5.compute-1.amazonaws.com` |
| `venus` | `ec2-1-2-3-6.compute-1.amazonaws.com` |

so far, so good. this setup works. however, it has the downside of requiring one public IPv4 address per instance, and as is well-known, IPv4 addresses are becoming scarce and increasingly expensive to use.

what is the best way to reduce the number of IPv4 addresses consumed by this server cluster?

Answer (score 1):

A reverse proxy such as an ALB would would work well. It probably has one public IP per AZ, but it can accept traffic for many domains and send it to the correct instance. You could also use an Nginx instance, but services are generally preferred over servers.

I have six personal domains hosted in AWS and no IPv4 addresses. My EC2 instances have IPv6 addresses, the DNS for the domains points at CloudFlare. CloudFlare contacts the server over IPv6 and makes the website available over IPv4. I've had no problems, it just took a little bit of experimentation with the Nginx configuration to get it working. I don't use a load balancer for my personal websites, for commercial websites I probably would.